# Order of UIMenuItems in custom edit menu

Tags: ios, uikit, uimenucontroller, uiresponder, uimenuitem

I want to add my own commands to the selection menu, but also keep the standard "copy", "cut", etc. commands. I use this:

```
    UIMenuItem *myItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Command" action:@selector(myCommand:)];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: myItem, nil]];
```

But this adds my command to the very end of the list in the edit menu. I want my command to appear first in it. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by myself. Here is what in my `initWithCoder:` method:

```
    UIMenuItem *myCommandItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Command" action:@selector(myCommandPressed:)];

    UIMenuItem *cutItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cut" action:@selector(myCut:)];
    UIMenuItem *copyItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(myCopy:)];
    UIMenuItem *pasteItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Paste" action:@selector(myPaste:)];
    UIMenuItem *selectItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" action:@selector(mySelect:)];
    UIMenuItem *selectAllItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select all" action:@selector(mySelectAll:)];
    UIMenuItem *deleteItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(myDelete:)];

    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: myCommandItem,
                                                           cutItem, copyItem, pasteItem, selectItem, selectAllItem, deleteItem, nil]];
```

Now this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(myCommandPressed:)) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (action == @selector(myCut:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(cut:) withSender:sender];
    }

    if (action == @selector(myCopy:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(copy:) withSender:sender];
    }

    if (action == @selector(myPaste:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(paste:) withSender:sender];
    }

    if (action == @selector(mySelect:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(select:) withSender:sender];
    }

    if (action == @selector(mySelectAll:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(selectAll:) withSender:sender];
    }

    if (action == @selector(myDelete:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:@selector(delete:) withSender:sender];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And finally:

```
- (void) myCommandPressed: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"My Command pressed");
}


- (void) myCut: (id) sender {
    [self cut:sender];
}

- (void) myCopy: (id) sender {
    [self copy:sender];
}

- (void) myPaste: (id) sender {
    [self paste:sender];
}

- (void) mySelect: (id) sender {
    [self select:sender];
}

- (void) mySelectAll: (id) sender {
    [self selectAll:sender];
}

- (void) myDelete: (id) sender {
    [self delete:sender];
}
```

Comment: I put the first block of code in initWithCoder of a ViewController, but the copy is still showing up first.