# Append custom UIMenuItems at the beginning of UIMenuController iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uimenucontroller

I have implemented a custom UIMenuController with two aditional options besides the ones that are set by default in iOS (cut, copy, look up, share). I want to keep these standard options, but I want them to appear after my two custom items, does anyone know how to achieve this in an *efficient* way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to implement this "hack" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056601/order-of-uimenuitems-in-custom-edit-menu but it didn't work (besides, it's a lot of repetitive code). I tried to find a solution all day, but couldn't get to any. I guess there's no way to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UIMenuController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller/1622811-menuitems) says:

> Custom items appear in the menu after any system menu items.

So there is probably no approved way around that. It appears to be baked in functionality.